# How to hide NavigationBar in SwiftUI for all types of devices?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view hierarchy like this: SplashView -> MainView.

SplashView doesn't need to have NavigationBar, so I disable it:

```
    NavigationView {
        VStack { /* some stuff */}        
    }    
         .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
         .navigationBarHidden(true)
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
```

In MainView I need an inline Navigation Bar

```
 NavigationView {
        ZStack{ /* some stuff */ } 
        }.navigationBarTitle("TEST TITLE", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EmptyView())
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                           Button("Test1") { print("test1")

                           }
                           Button("Test2") {
                               print("test2")
                   }
                       })
        }
```

As result, I have this on iPhone 11:

[image: MainView iPhone 11]

And on iPhone SE 2nd gen. (simillar on iPhone 8 etc.):

[image: MainView on iPhone SE 2nd gen.]

And if you manage, you can click "Back button" and go to the SplashView!

Why it works like this and what I should do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is you have the `NavigationView` as a root view for both screens. In this case you push the `NavigationView` in another `NavigationView`. So, you need the only one `NavigationView` in your project. So, change the `body` property of your MainView by removing the NavigationView

```
ZStack{ /* some stuff */ } 
    }.navigationBarTitle("TEST TITLE", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EmptyView())
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
                       Button("Test1") { print("test1")

                       }
                       Button("Test2") {
                           print("test2")
               }
                   })
```